# Is this Peter Pan quote attributable to J.M.Barrie?

Tags: quotes, peter-pan, j-m-barrie

The following quote is spoken at the very beginning of the 1953 *Peter Pan Movie*:

> All this happened before, and it will happen again. But this time it happened in London.

This is similar to the line used in the reimagined *Battlestar Galactica* series.

> All of this has happened before. All of this will happen again.

When searching online, [connections between these two quotes](https://www.sideshow.com/blog/10-profound-quotes-battlestar-galactica/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CAll%20of%20this%20has%20happened,Barrie%27s%20line%20from%20Peter%20Pan.) are made numerous times.

In most of these pages, the author of Peter Pan, [J.M. Barrie, is credited as being the originator of this quote](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/468991-all-of-this-has-happened-before-and-it-will-all).

But neither the Project Gutenberg version of the [Play](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0300081h.html) nor the [Book](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/16/pg16-images.html) actually contains this quote!

Is there any confirmation that this quote can be attributed to Barrie?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you take a lack of confirmation as confirmation that he did *not*, then, yes, it's very unlikely that the quote could be attributed to Barrie. First of all, J.M. Barrie died in 1937, well before the movie's production [had actually fully begun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Pan_(1953_film)#Return_to_actual_production). Though it's *possible* he'd scrawled it on some paper and left it on his deathbed, it's an unlikely scenario. Far likelier is that Disney's screenwriters simply interpolated the line for narrative effect or something.﻿

I, like you, was unable to find that line in any of the original books or plays for by J.M. Barrie.

In *[Revisiting Imaginary Worlds](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Revisiting_Imaginary_Worlds/MTQlDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA100&printsec=frontcover)*, Ron Moore (who worked on BSG), appears to attribute the quote to the movie, not the book itself:

> As Moore explained, the phrase "*all this has happened before, and all of it will happen again*” comes from the Disney movie version of Peter Pan.

The *[Yale Book of Quotations](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_New_Yale_Book_of_Quotations/FtU4EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA278&printsec=frontcover)* credits the line to the screenplay writer, Ted Sears- not to Barrie, another sign that he never wrote that line. It's probably just another one of those citogenetic fails.

Answer (score 27):

[This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=0OQoCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA49&pg=PA49#v=onepage&q&f=false) about men in Disney movies says the line is a paraphrase of Ecclesiastes 1:9 which says (in the [Good News Translation](https://www.bible.com/bible/69/ECC.1.9.GNTD)):

> What has happened before will happen again, What has been done before will be done again. There is nothing new in the whole world.

The internet is full of misattributed quotes, unless there are any reputable sources that attribute it to Barrie, I think it's safe to assume some people online just wrongly assumed it must come from Barrie because it's in the movie.

Comment: So, even if Barrie had written the line on a scrap of paper or whatnot, the quote (at least in sentiment) is so old that it'd be impossible to ascribe authorship.